# Evaluating the log of $(-2)^2=4$ (forgive my mathjax)

Tags: proof-verification, logarithms

While in my physics class the Pre-AP Precalc teacher (very smart man knows his calculus) came in with a problem. Using our advanced math skills we proceeded to <s>break math</s> become confused at where we went wrong. Where have we gone wrong?

$$
(-2)^2 = 4 \\
2 = \log_{-2}(4) \\
2 = \frac{\ln(4)}{\ln(-2)} \\
2 = \frac{\ln(4)}{\ln(2)+\pi i}
$$
Then you can quickly solve for i (assuming you know math).

Comment: Check whether $\log_{-2}(4)=\ln(4)/\ln(-2)$ is true.

Comment: By the same "reasoning" $\ln(-2) = \ln(2) + 3 \pi i$ so you get $2 \pi i = 0$.

Comment: @EclipseSun change of base

Comment: X in the first line but after that ????

Comment: @angryavian yes and then $0^2=-1$

Comment: @Isham opps fixed that

Comment: If only you can prove that for complex numbers.

Comment: You appear to be assuming that you can define a logarithm on the entire complex plane, which is not possible.

Comment: @RideTheWavelet I am confused by what you mean. ln(-2)=(ln(2)+Pi*i)

Comment: Okay but were this true, we would also have $\ln(-2)=\ln(2)+3\pi i,$ and equating these two values gives $2\pi i=0.$ So it's not that math is broken, this contradiction means that the logarithm doesn't make sense on the entire complex plane (as a function, anyway. Some sense can be made of it if we consider multivalued functions).

Comment: @RideTheWavelet interesting,

Comment: By the definition of complex log I know, $$\ln((-2)^2)=2\ln(2)+i(\arg(4)+2k\pi)=2\ln(2)+2k\pi i \ \mbox{with} \  k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: @Ixion is treating $\ln$ as a multivalued function here, which is correct. And in fact, the difficulty of your question disappears if we treat everything after the first time you take a logarithm as only being equal up to added multiples of $2\pi i.$

Comment: I got it now! Thanks @RideTheWavelet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a many-valued function, $\operatorname{Ln}(z)=\color{blue}\ln|z|+i\arg(z)+2k\pi i$ ($k\in\mathbb{Z}$), where $\arg(z)$ is a principal value of the argument of $z$. Here we use the blue $\color{blue}\ln$ to mean the real valued logarithm. If you fix some $k$, we write $\ln$ for that branch.

The problem is that $\ln(\exp(z))\ne z$ in general. Neither does $\ln(z^a)=a\ln(z)$ even if $a\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence, the rule of change of base does not hold.

You can check that

$$2 = \frac{\ln(4)}{\ln(-2)},$$

holds if and only if you take a branch cut not passing through $4$ and $-2$, and choose the argument correctly so that $\arg(4)=2\arg(-2)+2k\pi$.
If $\arg(z)\in(-3\pi/2,\pi/2)$ for example, you need to take $k=1$.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence, it doesn't hold for any of the branches you define (assuming you mean to take $-\pi <  \arg(z)<\pi.$), but it doesn't even really make sense to evaluate $\ln(4)/\ln(-2)$ on these branches since the branch cut is on the negative real axis which is one of the places you're trying to evaluate.  If you put the branch cut somewhere else (say along the positive imaginary axis) and so take $\pi/2< \arg(z) < 3\pi/2$ then $2 = \frac{\ln(4)}{\ln(-2)}$ holds.

Comment: That's correct. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: I wasn't correct. While it's true that the equation holds on the branch I described, it doesn't hold on all branches where the cut is not on the real axis. For instance take the same cut but with $-3\pi/2 < \arg(z) < \pi/2$ and we're back to OP's expression. In fact the one I described is the only branch on which it holds.

Comment: I've modified it again. Now it should be correct.